# How to test fragment properly in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, android-testing, ui-testing

I have been following the single activity model and MVVM in app development; So I have a single activity and the rest of UIs are all fragments. So, each single fragment is self-contained and I would like to test each single fragment without leaking state.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SplashFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun testVisibilityOfLogo() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<SplashFragment>()
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ivLogo))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

I have following test, which is throwing

```
Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED, STARTED, DESTROYED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")
```

I have followed the android docs as well:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing

According to the docs,

> After launching one of these fragment types, FragmentScenario drives
>   the fragment under test to the RESUMED state. This state indicates
>   that the fragment is running. If you're testing a graphical fragment,
>   it's also visible to users, so you can evaluate information about its
>   UI elements using Espresso UI tests.

It seems like it is not happening. Does anyone come across such a problem with UI testing with fragment?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I have forgot to add the following two dependencies in app level gradle in my case.

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.0-rc03'
debugImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0-alpha03'
```